# ¿Como inicializar sqlite desde (tarea asincrona) AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

Saludos. Soy novato en el desarrollo de aplicaciones en android y me gustaria que me apoyaran a resolver mi duda de como poder incializar SQLite desde una clase, en este caso estoy en una AsyncTask pero me marca un error en el contexto he visto algunas preguntas similares por aqui pero ninguna me ha dado resultado. En mi codigo tengo mi MainActivity, Una clase para SQLite y mi clase AsyncTask.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    _txtname1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtname1);
    _txtname2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtname2);

    _btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            _csqlite.insertar1(String.valueOf(_txtname1.getText()),String.valueOf(_txtname2.getText()));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Datos agregados con exito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Esta es mi clase SQLite

```
public class csqlite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public csqlite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query1="create table tbclientes(_ID integer primary key, User1 text, User2 text);";
    db.execSQL(query1);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
public void insertar1(String user1, String user2){
    this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("User1",user1);
    values.put("User2", user2);
    this.getWritableDatabase().insert("tbuser",null, values);
    this.getWritableDatabase().close();
}
public void  consulta1(){
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    String [] campos = new String[]{"User1","User2"};
    String [] args = new String[]{"1"};
    Cursor c = db.query("tbclientes",campos,"_ID=?",args,null,null,null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String usera=c.getString(0);
            String userb=c.getString(1);
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}
}
```

Y esta es mi clase AsyncTask desde la cual quiero inicializar SQLite y poder invocar al metodo consulta1.

```
public class background extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, Boolean>  {
csqlite _csqlite = new csqlite(this, "DB1.db", null, 1);

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clase `SyncTask<T,T,T>` no es un contexto para que le envies el parametro this:

```
public class background extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, Boolean>  {

   // esto es invalido, la clase no esun contexto por lo que te muestra un error
   csqlite _csqlite = new csqlite(this, "DB1.db", null, 1);

   //..
}
```

Especifica un constructor a la clase background  que acepte como parametro el Contex y se lo pasas a la instancia de la calse `csqlite`:

```
public class background extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, Boolean>  {

    csqlite _csqlite

    public background(Context context)
    {
      _csqlite = new csqlite(context, "DB1.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }

    //..
}
```

Entonces, siempre que vayas a inicializar la clase background, le tienes que enviar el contexto como parametro. Por ejemplo

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        _btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // ejecutamos la clase background enviando el contexto 
                background background = new background(MainActivity.this);
                background.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Exacto era lo que me faltaba. Gracias.